# Exclude folders by name in IntelliJ Idea PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is there a way to exclude / hide folders by pattern or name in PhpStorm, other than excluding them one by one with their full paths?

I got about 200 dreamweaver `_notes` folders in the project (one under each folder). These are ignored/hidden by a name pattern in other software we use. Can I hide them without actually adding 200 entries in PhpStorm?

Comment: **Settings | File Types | Ignore Files and Folders** field on the bottom. **PLEASE NOTE:** this is IDE-wide settings and will affect ALL projects

Comment: @LazyOne Wow just missed that one! Thank you -) Please write it as an answer so I can accept it, or I'll need to delete this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Settings | File Types | Ignore Files and Folders** field on the bottom part of the screen -- add your pattern there.

PLEASE NOTE:

- this is IDE-wide settings and will affect ALL projects
- it will be applied to both files and folders