# Exclude folders based on regular expressions in IntelliJ Idea PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is there any way to exclude folders in PhpStorm through regular expressions?

I have multiple "subproject" folders in my main project folder and every subproject has its own `vendor` folder I want to exclude from indexing.

So far I've been excluding those folders manually but since every week or so more subprojects are added the maintenance is annoying. If I decided to exclude another subproject folder, I'd have repeat that action for 30+ subprojects.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250544/exclude-folders-by-name-in-intellij-idea-phpstorm) suggests ignoring folders (which can use file masks to select files/folders), but I need to be able to see the folders in my project window and ignoring the folders hides them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250544/exclude-folders-by-name-in-intellij-idea-phpstorm) suggests ignoring folders (which uses regex to select files/folders)

It does not uses regex. It excludes by exact name or ordinary file masks (e.g. standard `*` char that means `any`).

---

Back to the subject -- it's not possible.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127753
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150784

Watch those and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: I've edited the last part of my question based on your correction, thanks.